# Image-mouse intersection / hover effect issue when using arrays

Tags: java, arrays, processing

I'm working on a small exercise that involves making an interface of six die faces. The goal is to change the color of each die face when I hover over it. The issue I'm having is that I can only change the color of the first die face, not the proceeding. I've been reluctant to come here and ask because I feel my issue is so insignificant but I've been trying to get this to work for the last 4 days and I just can't figure it out. I feel there is something about iteration that I'm just quite not understanding yet.

```
Dice[] dice = new Dice[6];
void setup(){
  size(600,100);
  for(int i = 0; i < dice.length; i++){
    dice[i] = new Dice(i*100,0,100,100);
  }
  imageMode(CORNER);
}

void draw(){
  for(int i = 0; i < dice.length; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < dice.length; j++){
      if(j!=i && dice[i].checkHover(mouseX,mouseY)){
        dice[i].drawDice(i,true);
      } else {
        dice[i].drawDice(i,false);
      }
    }
  }
}

class Dice{
  PImage[] diceFace = new PImage[6];
  PImage[] diceFaceHover = new PImage[6];
  int x;
  int y;
  int w;
  int h;

  Dice(int bx, int by, int bw, int bh){
    x = bx;
    y = by;
    w = bw;
    h = bh;
    for(int i = 0; i < dice.length; i++){//loads the images
      diceFace[i] = loadImage(i+".png");
      diceFaceHover[i] = loadImage(i+"h.png");
    }
  }

 void drawDice(int i, boolean hover){
   if(hover){
     image(diceFaceHover[i],x,y,w,h);
   } else {
     image(diceFace[i],x,y,w,h);
   }
 }

 boolean checkHover(float mx, float my){
   if((mx > x && mx < w) && (my > y && my < h)){
     return true;
   } else {
     return false;
   }
 }
}
```

I'll continue searching for a solution in the meantime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have bad condition for checking hover. Don't forget that `w` and `h` are same for all dices but you need position not size.

```
if( (mx > x & mx < x+w) && ( my >y && my < y+h ) )
```